# Balanced brackets conditional issue

Tags: ruby

I've been looking into Ruby and felt I was learning quite a bit. I'm currently trying to solve the balanced brackets algorithm but struggling with a condition. Here's what I have:

```
def balanced?(list_of_brackets)
    if list_of_brackets.length % 2 != 0
        false
    else
        stack = []
        bracket_sets = {
            '{' => '}', 
            '[' => ']', 
            '(' => ')'
        }
        list_of_brackets.chars do |bracket|
            if bracket == "{" or "[" or "("
                puts "#{bracket} is an opening bracket"
            else
                puts "#{bracket} is a closing bracket"
            end
        end
    end
    stack.empty?
end

puts balanced?('{}()[]')
```

The result I get is:

```
{ is an opening bracket
} is an opening bracket
( is an opening bracket
) is an opening bracket
[ is an opening bracket
] is an opening bracket
```

The closing brackets are somehow getting through the first condition. I'm missing something here but I can't spot it. Maybe another set of eyes can help me here. I'd appreciate any help and/or advice!

Comment: `if bracket_sets.key?(bracket)` would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if statement `if bracket == "{" or "[" or "("` needs to have a `bracket == X` for each `or` condition in the statement. Change:

```
if bracket == "{" or "[" or "("
```

to

```
if bracket == "{" or bracket == "[" or bracket ==  "("
```

...and that should work. The full code would be:

```
def balanced?(list_of_brackets)
    if list_of_brackets.length % 2 != 0
        false
    else
        stack = []
        bracket_sets = {
            '{' => '}', 
            '[' => ']', 
            '(' => ')'
        }
        list_of_brackets.chars do |bracket|
            if bracket == "{" or bracket == "[" or bracket ==  "("
                puts "#{bracket} is an opening bracket"
            else
                puts "#{bracket} is a closing bracket"
            end
        end
    end
    stack.empty?
end

puts balanced?('{}()[]')
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it! I thought of doing it like that but straight away ruled it out thinking it could be shortened. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome. I understand where you're coming from. I've done the same thing before as it feels right in the "natural" sense, but the way the conditions work in Ruby and most languages at the highest level `if (<boolean_condition>)`... so the logical operators must evaluate up to the whole statement

Comment: `balanced? ')))}' #=> true`, but that string is is not balanced.

Comment: `bracket =~ /^[{\[(]$/`?

Answer (score 3):

This

```
if bracket == "{" or "[" or "("
```

is basically checking if bracket is equal to "{" or if "[" is truthy or "(" is truthy, you missed the `bracket ==` for the rest of them. That's why they take the if branch and you get all of them are opening brackets. The solution for that problem is to compare every of them:

```
if bracket == "{" || bracket == "[" || bracket == "("
  ...
```

PS: make sure to not confuse `OR` with `||`, they have a different procedence.

Comment: Thank you! I thought of doing it like this but straight away ruled it out thinking it could be shortened. Appreciate the explanation and help!

Answer (score 3):

I will use the term *enclosures* to refer to parentheses (`'('` and `')'`), brackets (`'['` and `']'`) and braces (`'{'` and `'}'`). A string of enclosures is *balanced* if:

- each left parenthesis has a matching right parenthesis, and vice-versa;
- each left bracket has a matching right bracket, and vice-versa;
- each left brace has a matching right brace, and vice-versa; and
- all matched pairs are *well-nested* in the sense every each matched pair must be separated by a string comprised of zero or more matched pairs.

For example, `'([{}])'` is well-nested whereas `'([{]})'` is not, as the string separating the matched pair, `'['` and `]'`, namely `'{'`, is not a matched pair.

If, in the code in the question, the length of the string is even `stack` is initialized to an empty array that is never changed, so the return value `stack.empty?` will always be `true`. For example, `balanced?(')[') #=> true`. You need something like the following.

```
RIGHT_ENCLOSURE_PAIRS = { '}'=>'{', ']'=>'[', ')'=>'(' }
RIGHT_ENCLOSURES = RIGHT_ENCLOSURE_PAIRS.keys
```

```
def balanced?(str)
  stack = []
  str.each_char do |c|
    if RIGHT_ENCLOSURES.include?(c)
      return false if stack.empty? || stack.last != RIGHT_ENCLOSURE_PAIRS[c]
      stack.pop
    else
      stack << c
    end
  end
  stack.empty?
end
```

```
balanced? '{}()[]'             #=> true
balanced? '([{}])'             #=> true
balanced? '([{}]{})'           #=> true
balanced? '((([[[{{{}}}]]])))' #=> true
```

```
balanced? '{[]'                #=> false
balanced? '{{(([['             #=> false
balanced? '{()[{]}(([]))'      #=> false
```

I initially had the following *guard clause* as the first line of the method.

```
return false if str.length.odd?
```

After reflection, however, I removed it, as the time spent executing it unnecessarily for strings with even numbers of enclosures was probably much greater than the time saved for strings with odd numbers of enclosures.

I have not included `puts` statements such as `puts "#{c} is an opening enclosure"` as they would normally only be used for debugging, but they could of course be added if desired, in which case it might be more helpful to write

```
ENCLOSURE_TYPE = { '('=>'left parenthesis', ')'=>'right parenthesis',
                   '['=>'left bracket', ']'=>'right bracket',
                   '{'=>'left brace', '}'=>'right brace' }
```

```
puts "#{c} is a #{ENCLOSURE_TYPE[c]}"
```

Comment: `return false if stack.pop != RIGHT_ENCLOSURE_PAIRS[c]` would work, too.